# Output to file from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Challenge should you chose to accept it.. And if it's actually possible.

I have a stored procedure that gathers information in XML format and puts it in table field. I now need to select this table field and output it to an .XML file.

So:

```
SELECT TOP 1 xmlfield FROM excelTest
```

I have another stored procedure which is going to email this as an attachment to the person of choice.

I cannot use external methods i.e programs written in Java or C# etc.
I cannot use sqlcmd as it's blocked on security measures.
I'm using SQl Server 2008 so can't use INTO or other MySQL commands.

If anyone has any solutions for me that would be awesome.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: You didn't mention SSIS. Is that an option?

Comment: I believe that is okay, I'm not familiar with the process though if you wouldn't mind talking me through it?

Comment: That is a topic that is much bigger than an online forum. The learning curve is pretty steep but once you get the basics it isn't too bad at all. I would consider your task is a simple one in SSIS. Do some searching for basic SSIS tutorials and you will find hundreds and hundreds of them.

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame you can't use sqlcmd.
I'll leave some information about that here anyway in case it helps someone else.

To do this via sqlcmd you need a couple things.  In the sql you need to turn xml on and turn nocount on.  Then in the sqlcmd you specify the input and output files.
Here is an example of the sql used.  I guess you could put this in a stored procedure.  The FOR XML is the key that allows xml output from a query.  Getting the nesting right is quite tricky but you can see the examples of the nested queries below.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
:XML ON

select 
client.clnum as CompanyKey,
client.clname1 as Name,
client.crelated as CompanyNumber,
client.clnum as ClientNumber,
(select ISNULl(client.clname2,'') as AlternateName from client c1 where c1.clnum=client.clnum for XML path 
('AlternateNames'),type),
 (select 'COMPANY' as Type,ISNULL(c2.clbusi,'') as [Description],'True' as IsDefault,
  (
  select 
  (  
   select 
    (select [Order], LineValue from (
        select '1' as [Order], ISNULL(c4.claddr1,'') as LineValue from client c4 where c4.clnum=c3.clnum  
        union
        select '2' as [Order], ISNULL(c4.claddr2,'') as LineValue from client c4 where c4.clnum=c3.clnum
        union
        select '3' as [Order], ISNULL(c4.claddr3,'') as LineValue from client c4 where c4.clnum=c3.clnum
        union
        select '4' as [Order], ISNULL(c4.claddr4,'') as LineValue from client c4 where c4.clnum=c3.clnum
        union
        select '5' as [Order], ISNULL(c4.claddr5,'') as LineValue from client c4 where c4.clnum=c3.clnum
        union
        select '6' as [Order], ISNULL(c4.claddr6,'') as LineValue from client c4 where c4.clnum=c3.clnum
            ) as x where LTRIM(rtrim(x.LineValue)) !='' for xml path ('Line'),type)
   for xml path (''),type) as Lines,
   ISNULL(c3.clcity,'') as City,ISNULL(c3.clstate,'') as State,ISNULL(c3.clcountry,'') as Country,ISNULL(c3.clzip,'') as PostalCode 
   from client c3 where c3.clnum=c2.clnum for xml path (''),type) as [Address]
   from client c2 where c2.clnum=client.clnum for XML path ('CompanyLocation'),type) 
   as CompanyLocations         
  from client order by clnum 
for xml path ('Company'),root ('Companies')
set nocount off
```

Example of the sqlcmd.

```
sqlcmd -S <servername> -d <database> -E -i C:\\someinputpath\\Company.sql -o C:\\someoutputpath\\Company.xml
```

What I was curious about and couldn't really find the answer to was how this handles character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ole Automation Procedures if you have the permission. This is an example script which creates `C:\Temp\breakfast.xml` from an example XML selected from a TABLE variable.

Pretty it ain't, use it if other options are not practical or not allowed.

```
DECLARE @excel_test TABLE(xml_field XML);
INSERT INTO @excel_test(xml_field)VALUES(
'<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>');

DECLARE @data VARBINARY(MAX);
SET @data=(SELECT TOP 1 CAST(xml_field AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM @excel_test);

DECLARE @file_path VARCHAR(256) = 'C:\Temp\breakfast.xml';

DECLARE @hr INT;
DECLARE @object_token INT;

EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @object_token OUTPUT; -- Create instance
IF @hr<>0 GOTO __fail;
EXEC @hr=sp_OASetProperty @object_token, 'Type', 1;
IF @hr<>0 GOTO __cleanup;
EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @object_token, 'Open'; -- Open the stream
IF @hr<>0 GOTO __cleanup;
EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @object_token, 'Write', NULL, @data; -- Write data to the stream
IF @hr<>0 GOTO __close;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @object_token, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @file_path, 2; -- Save the stream to file

__close:
EXEC sp_OAMethod @object_token, 'Close'; -- Close the stream
__cleanup:
EXEC sp_OADestroy @object_token; -- Destroy the instance
__fail:
```

To enable `Ole Automation Procedures` (if you're allowed to of course), run this first to reconfigure settings:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```